# Getting only the subdocuments using couchbase N1QL

Tags: sql, database, couchbase, sql++, nosql

In our couchbase db, we have a bucket with relatively large objects. These objects have other objects inside let's say people. This should be an array, however for some reasons we had to create it as an object of objects, and this is how it looks like:

```
{
    "companyName": "company name",
    "companyid": "11111-GUID-11111",
    "people": {
        "22222-GUID-22222": {
            "peopleid": "22222-GUID-22222",
            "name": "name1"
        },
        "33333-GUID-33333": {
            "peopleid": "33333-GUID-33333",
            "name": "name2"
        },
        "44444-GUID-44444": {
            "peopleid": "44444-GUID-44444",
            "name": "name3"
        }
    }
}
```

Using this structure I can create a query for getting a "people" object using a query like the following:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM companies c
WHERE ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(c.people) SATISFIES v.peopleid = "22222-GUID-22222" END;
```

The problem with this structure is that the database responds with the whole company object, however I only need the "people" object which satisfies the condition, and I don't need people with other id than `"22222-GUID-22222"`.

Is there any way to achieve this using couchbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FIRST v FOR v IN OBJECT_VALUES(c.people) WHEN v.peopleid = "22222-GUID-22222" END AS people
FROM companies c
WHERE ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(c.people) SATISFIES v.peopleid = "22222-GUID-22222" END;
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some additional info regarding **how** your code solves the problem at hand. Doing so aids those with similar (but not identical) problems. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Comment: vsr, thank you for your help! It almost solves my problem. The only problem now is that I have to make queries like, let's say: I have to query every person which has age above 50. Using your query I'm only able to get the first match per document. If you could respond to this as well, then the answer would be complete and I could upvote and accept your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I was able to find a solution. I had to use the `ARRAY` statement instead of `FIRST` . I'm relatively new in couchbase, so it took some time to me. So I'm going to accept the answer. One more question though, is there any way to implement this using only one condition? I have to dynamically build these queries. If that would slow down the performance then I'm OK with this solution.

Comment: SELECT people
FROM companies c
LET people = ARRAY v FOR v IN OBJECT_VALUES(c.people) WHEN v.peopleid = "22222-GUID-22222" END
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(people) > 0;